# How to create macro to copy entire row at the active cell and paste below at active cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Google Sheets - Copy entire row at the active cell and paste below at active cell in a macro.

Simple to insert line below active cell.

```
function mcrPackagedPart() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeRow = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var activeRange = spreadsheet.getRange("A"+activeRow+":Z"+activeRow).getValues();
    // test
  spreadsheet.getRange(activeRange).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);    
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange(activeRange).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Comment: Yes, questions is "How to write a script to: Copy entire row at the active cell and paste below at active cell.

Comment: Your variable `activeRange` is actually an `Array` of an `Array` of values (aka "2D array"), because you used `Range#getValues()` on it. There isn't a method `Sheet#getRange` that takes a 2D array as a method parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you already found the Macro recording feature of Google Sheets because the code on the question.

While this feature could be useful, in order to be able to improve the recorded macro you should spend some time to learn the basics of JavaScript, Apps Script and the Spreadsheet Service. If you didn't this yet please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

The following show how could look the macros.gs file with an edited macro to keep the minimum required lines to insert a row above of the active cell:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
};
```